# Is there a way to make a CGPath grow by x Pixels?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-2d

I'm building a custom UIView, which draws its own content in a drawRect: Method. I want to stroke a CGPath with a color, and then grow this selection 1px and stroke with another color. Has somebody worked out a method to do this quite easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try applying an appropriate scaling transformation to your graphics context.

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately, that's not doing it. What it actually does is scaling everything (I only want a copy of a CGPath to grow). I'm looking for functionality similar to what you'd find in Graphics Editing Programs.

Comment: That depends entirely on the order of your calls. If you draw the original path first, then apply the scaling transform, then draw the second path, then revert the transform, only the second path will be transformed. Note that you will probably also have to adjust the stroke width by `1/scaleFactor` to counteract the transform.

Comment: Ok, got it now. I was calling them in the right order, except the path that I wanted to stroke was the same color as the background!!! Man, Friday is a killer. Thanks for all your help, I'll see if I can create a nice wrapper function to allow me to specify CGPath selection growth by a number of pixels. Cheers.

Comment: Scaling the context won't achieve this. Try scaling by a factor of 2.0 with any non-convex shape and you'll see. "Growing" a path requires more complex logic; it's boilerplate code (you have to iterate over every path node and shift it outwards along the line equidistant from the two adjacent line segments) but sadly Apple didn't include it in the standard library, so everyne has to re-write this common code for themselves :(.